# Is this thread safe? Breakpoints get hit multiple times

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
public class EmailJobQueue
{
    private EmailJobQueue()
    {

    }

    private static readonly object JobsLocker = new object();
    private static readonly Queue<EmailJob> Jobs = new Queue<EmailJob>();

    private static readonly object ErroredIdsLocker = new object();
    private static readonly List<long> ErroredIds = new List<long>();

    public static EmailJob GetNextJob()
    {
        lock (JobsLocker)
        {
            lock (ErroredIdsLocker)
            {
                // If there are no jobs or they have all errored then get some new ones - if jobs have previously been skipped then this will re get them
                if (!Jobs.Any() || Jobs.All(j => ErroredIds.Contains(j.Id)))
                {
                    var db = new DBDataContext();
                    foreach (var emailJob in db.Emailing_SelectSend(1))
                    {
                        // Dont re add jobs that exist
                        if (Jobs.All(j => j.Id != emailJob.Id) && !ErroredIds.Contains(emailJob.Id))
                        {
                            Jobs.Enqueue(new EmailJob(emailJob));
                        }
                    }
                }

                while (Jobs.Any())
                {
                    var curJob = Jobs.Dequeue();
                    // Check the job has not previously errored - if they all have then eventually we will exit the loop
                    if (!ErroredIds.Contains(curJob.Id))
                        return curJob;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ReInsertErrored(long id)
    {
        lock (ErroredIdsLocker)
        {
            ErroredIds.Add(id);
        }
    }
}
```

I then start 10 threads which do this:

```
var email = EmailJobQueue.GetNextJob();
if (email != null)
{
     // Breakpoint here
}
```

The thing is that if I put a breakpoint where the comment is and add one item to the queue then the breakpoint gets hit multiple times. Is this an issue with my code or a peculiarity with VS debugger?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Do you realize that this: `Jobs.All(j => ErrorIds.Contains(j.Id))` is checking every job against every error id, and if your lists get even moderately large it's going to be a serious performance problem? You probably want a way to improve your filtering.

Comment: What does `db.Emailing_SelectSend(1)` do?

Comment: Come to think of it, this looks like a standard producer/consumer application. You should consider rewriting it so that you have one thread that populates a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx), and your worker threads read from that. Doing things that way will greatly simplify your program.

Comment: If that's the extent of your code, I don't see the benefit of two lock objects. One should be sufficient.

Comment: Also, `ReInsertErrored` isn't actually called from the sample code.

Comment: As a side note, since all methods and members of the class are `static`, you should mark the class itself as `static` and ditch the `private` constructor.

Comment: Jim - They shouldn't get too large but they might, I'll look in to it.
Jim - I'll have a look at that pattern. Thanks.
Hatchet - Yes I'll fix that.

Comment: To avoid the explicit locking, you might want to try using thread-safe collections? Would make your code simpler and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as if you are getting your jobs from the database:

```
foreach (var emailJob in db.Emailing_SelectSend(1))
```

Is that database call marking the records as unavailable for section in future queries?  If not, I believe that's why you're hitting the break point multiple times.

For example, if I replace that call to the database with the following, I see your behavior.

```
// MockDB is a static configured as `MockDB.Enqueue(new EmailJob{Id = 1})`

private static IEnumerable<EmailJob> GetJobFromDB()
{
    return new List<EmailJob>{MockDB.Peek()};
}
```

However, if I actually Dequeue from the mock db, it only hits the breakpoint once.

```
private static IEnumerable<EmailJob> GetJobFromDB()
{
    var list = new List<EmailJob>();

    if (MockDB.Any())
        list.Add(MockDB.Dequeue());

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Ah you are correct. I do delete the item from the database but I do it after where the breakpoint is set so I could conceivably get the same item twice. This could also happen in a production environment. Thank you very much for spotting that, I wouldn't have.

Comment: The only reason I spotted it is because I tried to run your code, but I didn't have a DB, so I just stubbed out the call.

Comment: Well that almost made it in to a production environment - if I could upvote you twice I would.

Answer (score 2):

This is a side effect of debugging a multi-threaded piece of your application.

You are seeing the breakpoint being hit on each thread. Debugging a multi-threaded piece of the application is tricky because you're actually debugging all threads at the same time. In fact, at times, it will jump between classes while you're stepping through because it's doing different things on all of those threads, depending on your application.

Now, to address whether or not it's thread-safe. That really depends on how you're using the resources on those threads. If you're just reading, it's *likely* that it's thread-safe. But if you're writing, you'll need to leverage at least the `lock` operation on **shared objects**:

```
lock (someLockObject)
{
    // perform the write operation
}
```

Comment: Well, this sounds like more of a race condition to me.  If `EmailJobQueue.GetNextJob()` succeeds, then the next call to it should be null.  Only one thread should get the job.

Comment: But surely a single thread should get it, which then satisfies the if condition, hits the breakpoint and then the debugger kicks in?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, on a single thread, yes I see what you're saying. But unless I misunderstood he starts up 10 threads that do the same thing and his breakpoint is inside the `if`. It **feels** like it's hit more than once, but it's actually being hit on different threads.

Comment: But it shouldn't be hit on different threads because it get Dequeued and should only be returned once - unless the above class isn't thread safe.